# Trying to find a movie with fantasy religion-based world

Tags: identify-this-movie

I am trying to locate a movie that I saw only a few scenes to while recovering from some injuries. If I am remembering correctly, the protagonist exists in a society where everyone has a religion, save himself. I believe there were some characters (guards, police) who wore trench coats and had white face masks on (like Rorschach); and there was a receptionist who had just switched religions to something like "7th day adventists."

Can anyone recall this movie? I want to say it was a more recent (last 5 years) film, but I am not certain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is Franklyn. Here is a [link to it](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0893402/). However, I wouldn't count on too much action. There are three important characters, each one with its own story, one of them sounding very similar to what you described here: in a world where every person must have a religion(even if it is a very weird one, more like a club), an atheist becomes a vigilante, trying to find and kill the head of a criminal... religion. Although this may seem like a film packed with action, there are quite few thrilling scenes. The intention of the filmmakers was to make you ask yourself some questions regarding religion, faith, existence and other philosophical topics. But, this goal doesn't seem to me as being achieved. In my opinion, they aimed at too many things at once.

Hope it will be helpful.